# Seeding data using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I'm trying to create an `ApplicationUser` which has a `User` as a child object, this is what the models look like:

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("AspNetUser")]
   public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

Within my DbContext I have:

```
public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options)
   : base(options)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
      builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AdminConfiguration());
   }
}
```

AdminConfiguration:

```
public class AdminConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        var id = "bc62cdff-77ca-4473-a467-210eb36fdd5d";
        var admin = new ApplicationUser
        {
           Id = id,
           UserName = "admin",
           NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
           Email = "admin@dotvvm.com",
           NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@DOTVVM.COM",
           EmailConfirmed = true,
           SecurityStamp = new Guid().ToString("D")
        };

        admin.PasswordHash = GeneratePassword(admin, "Admin12345!");
        builder.HasData(admin);
        builder.OwnsOne(a => a.User).HasData(new User
        {
          Id = 1,
          AspNetUserId = id,
          FirstName = "Test",
          LastName = "Test"
        });
     }

     private string GeneratePassword(ApplicationUser user, string password)
     {
        var passHash = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        return passHash.HashPassword(user, password);
     }
  }
```

With this code, I create a migration and try to execute `Update-Database` but I get this error:
`To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, does anyone know?

Comment: Could you provide migration Up method?

Comment: Also, it seems you are using EF Core, not EF. Am i right? If so, are you sure your One-to-One relationship is configured properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure that you're using .OwnsOne wrong (but i doubt it is root cause, i speak about it later)
Owned types are Value objects. Value objects have no identity on their own and exist only as a part of their owner like

```
//this is entity, it has identity
public class Person
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Name Name { get; set; }
}
//and this is value object and could be owned type
public class Name
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

If you want both `ApplicationUser` and `User` to be entities (make sense) you could consider One-to-One relationship betwen them, like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(a => a.User)
        .WithOne(b => b.ApplicationUser)
        .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(b => b.AspNetUserId);
}
```

and then your

```
builder.HasData(new User
        {
          Id = 1,
          AspNetUserId = id,
          FirstName = "Test",
          LastName = "Test"
        });
```

might be valid and ... might not

because another possible source of you problem could be Autoincrement Id field (is it autoincrement in your `User` class?)

If so -

```
builder.OwnsOne(a => a.User).HasData(new User
        {
          Id = 1, //<<---- try removing this
          AspNetUserId = id,
          FirstName = "Test",
          LastName = "Test"
        });
```

this could solve your issue